# Import MS Access 2010 database into MYSQL Workbench v6,3

Tags: odbc, ms-access-2010, mysql-workbench

I am trying to import a MS ACCESS 2010 database into a new MySQL database.

Since I have a 64 bit machine I have used the ODBC tool ODBCac32 to create a 32 bit ODBC connection since the 64 bit ODBC administrator has an issue with a 32 bit application.

The issue I am having is that the MySQL workbench is using the 64 bit ODBC connector and then fails to import.  Is there a way to force it to to use the 32 bit ODBC connector and 32 bit ODBC connection?

Thanks

Comment: Try to use the 32bit version of the MySQL workbench. IMHO that must use the 32bit version of the driver, while the 64bit version must use the 64bit driver. Looks like you've installed 64bit version if its currently using the 64bit driver.

Comment: Good idea, but I have managed to resolve the issue using the third party tool "Bullzip MS Access to MySQL".